# Close form in a timed event

Tags: c#, forms, timer, timed-events

I can't make the form "frmDOOR" close in 'OnTimeEvent'.

```
frmDOOR close = new frmDOOR
close.close();
```

It's not working. It even makes the timedevent repeat itself even though I have autoreset set to false. I hope you can find out what I'm doing wrong, it's driving me crazy!

```
public partial class frmDOOR : BASEFORM
{
    public frmDOOR()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 1000;
        aTimer.AutoReset = false;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;           
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {                
        frmUser regform = new frmUser();
        regform.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;            
        regform.ShowDialog();
    }        
}
```

Comment: it throws a  Cross-thread operation exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the current instance of your form you simply refer to it with `this` (that isn't even needed as you're calling its own methods).

Use the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to overcome cross-thread issues.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer aTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public frmDOOR()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    aTimer.Tick += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 1000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;           
}



private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
{                
    this.Close();
    // or even shorter just Close();
    // let's stop the timer as well
    aTimer.Stop();

    frmUser regform = new frmUser();
    regform.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;            
    regform.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a `System.Timers.Timer`, it calls its event on a different thread.
Simply use a [`Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). You can create it within the form desinger and also its `Tick` event. The timer isnt' very precise, but good enough for most cases.

Comment: This looks like a better solution than accepted answer.